# Can't use www.saberparts.com

Tags: java, flash

When I go to a website that looks like using flash or java or somthing similar, it says that "your current browser isn't compatible with saberparts" and I actualized firefox, tried it with chrome, installed flash and java complement. I use ubuntu mate 15.04.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the site works fine on 14.04 and FF. You don't happen to be affiliated with it?

Comment: Related?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/671297/webgl-not-workin-with-intel-corporation-mobile-945gse-express-integrated-graphic

Comment: why the question of affiliation?

Comment: @michael cuz it might be an ellaborate way to spam that website ;-) But the moderator answered it so don't read too much into that comment.

Comment: strange, don't even know about what kinf of technique this might be... no, I just would like to use the website and I am not able to....

Comment: Proof please or will consider your question as spammy promotion.

Comment: Sonickyle please explain yourself, I am not spending the whole day on a computer and I don't even understand what a spammy promotion means. I might guess that the whole point of my question is to promote the website??? How to proof it???? WHat do you want? A screenshot of the error message???? Or do I have to remove the website in the question????

Comment: I did remove the link and I hope you are happy for that.... and I definitivly have no affiliation or whatsoever with that website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't using Java or Flash. It's Three.js which uses WebGL.

It might be possible your browsers aren't seeing a 3D graphics device powerful enough, or it might be that you don't have the drivers set up correctly, or it could just be that you don't have your browser set correctly.

I'd start with the last by viewing [the official WebGL support page](https://get.webgl.org/). If that doesn't work it will direct you to your browser's settings. If that doesn't work, it's time to look at your graphics setup in Ubuntu.

---

It seems your Intel 945 integrated graphics might be so underpowered that it's [been blacklisted](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Blocklisting/Blocked_Graphics_Drivers#Intel_cards) to stop things grinding to a halt. It might also just not support enough features.

However you can [force Firefox to ignore the blacklist](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Blocklisting/Blocked_Graphics_Drivers#How_to_force-enable_blocked_graphics_features) by opening `about:config` in Firefox (put that in the address bar) and setting the following keys to `true`:

```
webgl.force-enabled
layers.acceleration.force-enabled
```

This may make Firefox crash however.

Comment: Ok, thank you Oli, by following the link to the WEbGl page, I got: Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card.

Comment: Ok, I got:    lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Comment: I've added a block about forcing WebGL on but it may break Firefox. You may have to resign to the fact your onboard graphics card isn't powerful enough.

Comment: yes, firefox crashes, so it has only to do with the grahic card? the same would happen using another internet browser or even windows??

Comment: [Windows users seem to have the same problems with various Intel cards](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=594877). I would expect the same would apply here under Windows.

Comment: @michael As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Ok, I clicked on it, sorry guys I did forget that... there were quite a lot of instructions when beginning with the website...